# Ember.js testing component with service dependency

Tags: testing, ember.js

I'm trying to write tests for my addon, but encountering some weird behaviour.

I have created a service (via ember-cli generate), which is used inside a component.
When an actual application is running everything is working fine.

However, when testing the component I get an error saying that the service is undefined when trying to access any of its properties/methods.

In the test i've put the service in "needs" like so:

`needs: ['service:my-service']`

"Needing" other components (e.g. child ones used inside) works as expected, services strangely fail.

Are there any additional steps that need to be done?

Running ember-cli 0.1.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using the new `Ember.inject` API available in the latest (as of writing) [1.10 release](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_injected-properties).

Apparently the new inject API is intended to replace `needs` in the future, it also works great with unit tests.

Comment: It should look something like this:
```export default Ember.Component.extend({
  cart: Ember.inject.service('shopping-cart')
});```

as shown in the docs here (accessing services) - http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services

Answer (score 1):

When you generate a service, it also generates an initializer whose job it is to inject the service into the various places that you need it.

So, when you run *acceptance* tests your app will have booted and initializers will have been run, therefore the services will be available.

However, when *unit* testing components you get a clean container (better for testing). You just need to inject what you need:

```
moduleForComponent('foo-bar', null, {
  setup: function(container) {
    container.register('service:foo', FooService);
    container.injection('component', 'fooService', 'service:foo');
  }
});
```

Comment: When I run `App = startApp();` I can see console logs from the initializer which is injecting the service into the component. I don't know if this means that it's is properly injecting it though. I tried your method, but I get `FooService is undefined`, surrounded it with quotes, but I got `Failed to create an instance of 'service:foo'.` I have a minimal setup replicating my problem [here](https://github.com/rk1/foobar) if you are interested.

Comment: Andrew's solution worked for me (I'm not on Ember 1.10 yet so can't use `Ember.inject`).

Comment: @rk1: You need to import your service at the top of your test file. Something like `import FooService from '../../../services/foo';`. That's why you're getting the `FooService is undefined` error.

Answer (score 0):

We just managed to get one working using `needs: ['service:myService']` instead of `needs: ['service:my-service']`.